# How can i revert all the changes made onto the document through jsx script?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, extendscript, jsx, photoshop-script, adobe-indesign

I want any of the way that can help me to revert all the changes that are made on the document ,like through **Jsx script**  I made changes in the document like placing image re-sizing image changing swatches etc. but at a point of time i want to revert all the changes made through the same **`jsx code`**. i'm aware of `undo function in Jsx` but undo  function  just revert the recent change (can say last change ) so ,is there any way that can be used to revert all the changes.

**Note:** one way i know that is to close the document without save changes and reopen the same document. but avoiding this solution.

Comment: Snapshot it before you start maybe?

Comment: how can i take snapshot ? do u mean to keep a copy ?

Comment: Like this `var savedState = docRef.activeHistoryState;`

Comment: what should be docRef ? is it app.documents[0]

Comment: Have a liitle look here... https://gist.github.com/commadelimited/1641963

Comment: not able to store active reference in illustrator

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the main functionality in the script inside a function, say `main()`, so that calling `main()` will run the script.

Now add the following line to the end of the script:

```
app.activeDocument.suspendHistory('My changes', 'main()');
```

This will run the `main()` function and in your History panel you would see a new undo state called 'My changes'. Undoing this would revert all the changes you did from the script.

Answer (score 0):

to go back to the initial history state, just use:
app.activeDocument.activeHistoryState = app.activeDocument.historyStates[0];